# Google Sheet show students latest submitted score per date

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Im running a Google Form Quiz and responses into a Google Sheet called "Data" with checking for Student name in column A and Quiz name in column B. Column B pulls pass/fails from Quiz response sheet.

Students can pass with passes over 80% and fail under 80%.

Sheet is checking Form Responses sheet with VLOOKUP.

My issue is how to show the student latest submission in Data. Its only the first submission, that appears on the Data sheet.

I think its something with Sorting but can not figure out how to sort ongoing quiz submissions and then show the students latest score by date..! Please help :)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

2nd parameter of `VLOOKUP` needs to be sorted in descending order

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, SORT(Form!A:B, 1, 0), 2, 0)))
```